Issues intalling MacOS High Sierra on Patriot SSD
My problem is that I have my mom's old MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) which has an old magnetic drive running very slowly. I tried formatting it from an external bootable USD drive with MacOS High Sierra (which I confirmed is compatible with this device) but during the process (which I've performed before many times) corrupted the hard drive and I had issues trying to perform the install again.
I later thought it would also be worth getting a new SSD instead of continuing with the old magnetic drive as I'd been made aware of examples from family/friends that they'd done a similar upgrade and their devices started performing much better. So I bought the following SSD from Amazon:
Patriot P210 SATA 3 512GB Computer Data Storage Internal Solid State Drive 2.5" SSD- P210S512G25 From Amazon
I also bought a SATA to USB3.0 adapter cable per below
SZJUNXIAO SATA to USB 3.0 Adapter Cable Support SATA III UASP, USB to SATA 22 Pin Converter for 2.5" Hard Disk Drives HDD and Solid State Drives SSD, Max 5TB-Black from Amazon
I have my own old MacBook Air (13-inch, Late 2010) to which I then connected the new Patriot SSD via the SATA cable and booted into the MacOS High Sierra Bootable USD via another USB port. I then formatted the new Patriot drive using the APFS (the GUID partition table was not available) and then proceeded to install a new version of MacOS on the same Patriot drive.
Everything seems to be working okay for a while and then when there's about 13 minutes left in the install a window pops up saying the installation could not be completed on this device and to run a diagnostics check. I did a health check through the drive utility on the bootable drive and it has shown no errors.
I then read some articles in which it was mentioned that there are only certain SSD manufacturers on which MacOS can install successfully and thereafter run without issues. One such brand I've found through research is Crucial which I can buy
Crucial BX500 240GB 3D NAND SATA 2.5-inch SSD - CT240BX500SSD1,Black/Blue from Amazon
I'm happy to go ahead and purchase this SSD but I just wanted to get an idea from the community here on whether this will help or if I'm doing something wrong with the existing Patriot SSD that I've purchased?
Apologies for the long post but I thought I'd provide as much information as possible so that you guys can provide the most informed response.

At least in my experience, I haven't had issues with specific SSDs being incompatible with macOS, especially not SATA ones (there were a few Samsung NVMe drives that had firmware issues that didn't play well with macOS, but that's the only thing I'm aware of.) I don't the issue is the SSD. Can you provide a photo of the error you encountered?

Thanks @JMY1000 for your response. I did some further work on this today and surprisingly I formatted my MacBook Air (it's mostly a backup laptop so was okay) and tried to install High Sierra - it didn't work - same error. I'm now thinking that the bootable installer is probably corrupt - it's an old flash drive. I'm going to try create a fresh bootable install and try again Will then add here whether the install worked even on the Patriot SSD. Story continues.

A couple of updates since OP. I erased my own MacBook Air (13-inch, Late 2010)'s drive (it's a backup laptop so was okay with that) and tried to do the fresh install of High Sierra on that one (which has worked many times in the past before) and surprisingly, the same error happened (which was happening with the fresh install on the Patriot SSD) - which has now led me to think that my bootable installer (old flash drive) has gone corrupt. So I'll have to create a new bootable install for High Sierra to get that laptop working again
But I actually was able to complete a new install on the Patriot SSD. It was pretty much done using the recovery tool on the MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) which even though had it's OS wiped, had a Catalina recovery tool which was still operational and through that was able to install a new Catalina OS on the Patriot SSD. I formatted using APFS and the install worked smoothly. I then also did the subsequent OS update after connecting it to the internal SATA cable and that worked smoothly as well. So the MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) is pretty much good now.
So in summary, I don't believe there's any issue with using a Patriot SSD as an upgrade for a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) - just ensure the method being used for the OS install (in my case the bootable USB installer) has been recently checked to work reliably.
